# is it possible to print the keys of a hashmap with a specific form?

Tags: java, junit, hashmap

I'm about working with Junit test , hashmap in java .
My code looks like :

```
HashMap <String,String> var = new HashMap <String,String>(); 
var.put("key1","value1");
var.put("key2","value2");
var.put("key3","value3");
var.put("key4","value4");

Iterator<String> itKey = var.keySet().iterator();

String Existing_coaches = "" ;

 while(itKey.hasNext()){

 String key = (String)itKey.next();

// Existing_coaches = i use concat function 

    } 
 return  Existing_coaches ;
```

What i want to do is to return the itkeys as this forms :

key1, key2, key3, key4

we start with the first key + comma etc .

so i need to know what's the first key and the last one .

Any idea on how we can do that ?

Comment: `String.join(", ", var.keySet())`

Comment: @shmosel : but Where ?

Comment: For clarification, when you say "first key" do you mean (1) the first one inserted or (2) the first one in alphabetical order? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Join the keys with a comma and a space:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, String> m = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        m.put("key1", "val1");
        m.put("key2", "val2");
        m.put("key3", "val3");
        m.put("key4", "val4");
        System.out.println(String.join(", ", m.keySet()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
key1, key2, key3, key4
```

Comment: @ernest_k No, it's not. Take a look at [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: it doesnt return the result in the order of insertion .

Comment: Sorry about that, it wasn't clear to me that that was desired. I see know that in your question "first key" could indeed mean "first one inserted" but it could also be read as first one in alphabetical order or just the generic first one output. As you probably know, `HashMap`s are by their very nature unordered, but `LinkedHashMap`s iterate in the order of insertion. I've edited the answer to show that. Also `TreeMap` iterates the keys in alphabetical order if they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with String.join, use the first one, or use the second if you like it. Both ways work:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Hash {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap <String, String> var = new HashMap <String, String>(); 

        var.put("A", "1");
        var.put("B", "2");
        var.put("C", "3");
        var.put("D", "4");

        System.out.println("method 1: " + myHash(var));
        System.out.println("method 2: " + myHash2(var));
    }

    public static String myHash(HashMap var) {
        Iterator<String> itKey = var.keySet().iterator();
        String Existing_coaches = "" ;

        while(itKey.hasNext()){
            String key = (String)itKey.next();
            Existing_coaches = Existing_coaches + key + ", ";
        }

        return  Existing_coaches.substring(0, Existing_coaches.length() -2) ;
    }

    public static String myHash2(HashMap var) {
        return String.join(", ", var.keySet());
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
method 1: A, B, C, D
method 2: A, B, C, D
```

Comment: i don't understand , i don't get result in order of insertion

Comment: Yes i did it works , but when i tried to do the same with my code i always get the result in reverse of insertion , i have a test that adds the keys and values , and after that another test that shows if it's equals to key1, key2, key3, key4 but it fails as i get key4, key3, key2, key1

Comment: Did you know that a HashMap does not guarantee order? A Map is not an ordered data structure, so you can not trust that the output will have the order you want. If you want that, you have to use a LinkedHashMap or TreeMap (and in this last case you still have to take care of the keys).

Comment: This make it more clear , okey i'll try using instead LinkedHashMap .

Comment: Ok, I think you got it. After you do ur tests, post your conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
       Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

       // Approach 1 : use advanced for (foreach) loop
        StringBuilder keyString = new StringBuilder();
        for(String key: map.keySet()){
            keyString = keyString.append(key + ", ");
        }
        String resultStr = keyString.toString().substring(0, keyString.toString().length()-2); // deducting 2 for comma and space
        System.out.println(resultStr);

        // Approach 2: use for loop
        StringBuilder keyString2 = new StringBuilder();
        Object[] keySet =  (Object[]) map.keySet().toArray();
        for(int i=0; i < keySet.length; i++) {
            if(i == keySet.length-1) {
                keyString2 = keyString2.append(keySet[i].toString());
            } else {
                keyString2 = keyString2.append(keySet[i].toString() + ", ");
            }

        }
        System.out.println(keyString2.toString());

        // Approach 3: Use String join
        System.out.println(String.join(", ", map.keySet()));
```

Comment: i don't understand , i don't get result in order of insertion

Comment: LinkedHashMap is used which actually maintains the insertion order